# T-SQL Union (distinct, not all) and Order by with priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, union

Assume I have a `Tag` table (`Id int` and `Name nvarchar(100)`) with 3 values:

```
1 Software
2 Hardware
3 Warehouse
```

Now I want to query with keyword, and prioritize the ones that starts with the keyword over the containing one. So at first I write this query:

```
SELECT 0 AS SortCol, * 
FROM Tag T
WHERE CHARINDEX(@keyword, T.Name) = 1
UNION
SELECT 1 AS SortCol, * 
FROM Tag T
WHERE T.Name LIKE ('%' + @keyword + '%')
ORDER BY SortCol, Name;
```

However that did not work because the `SortCol` column no longer make them distinct (the `Warehouse` value appears twice because it is correct in both).

[image]

That's when I think I need to manually call `DISTINCT` by getting rid of that column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.Id, T2.Name
FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS SortCol, * 
     FROM Tag T
     WHERE CHARINDEX(@keyword, T.Name) = 1
     UNION
     SELECT 1 AS SortCol, * 
     FROM Tag T
     WHERE T.Name LIKE ('%' + @keyword + '%')
     ORDER BY SortCol, T.Name) AS T2;
```

However, this does not work because I get this error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

What am I missing here? How can I use `UNION` with `ORDER BY` in both statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `UNION` you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM   Tag T
WHERE  T.Name LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%'
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN T.Name LIKE @keyword + '%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
          Name;
```

Comment: Yes this is the case I need for this question. The correct ORDER BY statement should be `CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@keyword, T.Name) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1`

Comment: @LukeVo - why do you think that is more correct then what I have? `T.Name LIKE @keyword + '%'` doesn't have a leading wildcard

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't notice the missing `%` there. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you need this `SortCol` column it is possible:

```
DECLARE @keyword NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'ware';

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) rn
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS SortCol, * 
    FROM Tag T
    WHERE CHARINDEX(@keyword, T.Name) = 1
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS SortCol, * 
    FROM Tag T
    WHERE T.Name LIKE ('%' + @keyword + '%')) s
)
SELECT SortCol, Id, name
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY SortCol, Name;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9eb86092683e68d528c488a0a04f3500)**

Comment: Thanks, although for this specific case I don't need it but I might need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a CASE in the ORDER BY clause directly, like :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Tag
WHERE name like ( '%' + @keyword + '%' ) 
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(@keyword, T.Name) = 1 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END,
    names
```